# Mic bodypack with wired output?

Tags: microphone, computer

Is there such a thing as a wireless mic bodypack that also has a 3.5mm output? I want the flexibility to connect an earset mic to a computer headset input jack.

Comment: Google says yes - but why do you need a cable from the transmitter when you already have one from the receiver? or… why not plug the mic directly to a mic preamp, rather than via the body-pack?

Comment: Sort of unclear what you are asking for. Do you want: 1) a wireless system system where  the receiver has a 3.5 output to your computer? 2) connect a mic to your computer with a cable or 3) both a wireless system and connect with a cable ?? 1) and 2)  both exist as products at different price levels.

Comment: That's a good point- number 2 is what I'm really after. Want to take something like a Shure MX153T stage quality headset mic and marry it up to in ear monitors for a top notch computer headset. I do want something that I can use with a mobile phone too, with a 3.5mm TRRS connector at the end of the day.